# Multiple Windows in a non-Document-based Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, nswindowcontroller

I am building a Non-Document-based cocoa app that I want to behave as follows:

- The main window contains a Table View with a list of items (backed by Core Data).
- Each item should open in its own window
- likewise, clicking on the new-item button should open a new-item window, with multiple such windows openable at the same time.

In my app delegate, which currently handles the table view, I implemented the following method to open a new Item Window:

```
-(IBAction)newItem:(id)sender {

    MyItemWindowController *itemController = [[MyItemWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"MyItemWindowController"];

    [itemController showWindow:self];

}
```

The window does show, **but it disappears almost immediately**. If however, I instantiate a Window Controller that is an instance variable of my appDelegate, the window does stick around, but obviously, only one such window can remain open at any given time.

I would really like to have the mentioned functionality, but do not want to use the Document-based architecture, as I don't need to be able to save items as documents to disk.

Any suggestions? I know I must be missing something really basic, but I just cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing your window disappeared because of ARC (not too familiar with it, so I'm not certain if that's the reason), so just do what you said, but instead of having a MyItemWindowController as your instance variable, have an array as your instance variable that adds a new window controller whenever you need another new window.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.. I actually tried doing this earlier, but forgot to initialize the array :)

Comment: And how do you release each window when they're closed?

Comment: Mmm I think you just tell the AppDelegate's array of windows to remove the object equals to the closing window.